# Joomla 2.5 jQuery with TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I've been looking around for a fair while today, and i cant seem to get it working.

As i want to use the .remove() functions and its likes from jQuery, i thought it would be a "easy transition" over.

Currently on Joomla 2.5.9, and trying to access TinyMCE in the article-editor.

Anyone been able to do this?

I would need to load the content of that editor into a temporary div or var, then use somethign like `$('#tmp').remove('...');` and finally put it back in to the active editor.

Problem is i keep getting null in return, regardless of what i try :(

Answer (score 1):

You will need to go through the [TinyMCE Javascript API](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3atinymce.api.3.x) to accomplish this. I have performed a similar task for a recent project and I can recommend the following approach:

```
tinyMCE.onAddEditor.add( function() {
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.onChange.add( function( ed ) {
         var content = ed.getContent();

         // process the content here
         // ...

         ed.setContent( content );
    });
});
```

The `getContent()` method returns the entire text in the editor frame, including the HTML tags. You could afterwards load it dynamically as HTML and manipulate it:

```
$( content ).remove( '...' );
```

Comment: Hm, i am not sure how to use this. In my edit.php file (Yes, i have to edit the core files to add custom fields in the article editor), i have a field with a dropdown showing the albums in a gallery (my own component). When i chose one, it will be inserted with `<div id="container_gallery_{id}"><img src="...thumb.jpg" /></div>`. It is this div i need removed with jQuery, as if there are 2 galleries stuck next to eachother, the normal `content.replace(regex)` will remove both.

Comment: Never mind that, i think i got it working properly with:`var regex = new RegExp('<div id="container_gallery_'+a+'"(.*?)>[^~]*?<\/div>','gi');`